# trying to draw using Turtle

Tags: python-3.x, drawing

i have written a simple code that should draw a square, see below:

```
    from turtle import Screen,Turtle
    def draw(directions,length,angle,x=0,y=0):
        s = Screen
        t = Turtle
        t.up()
        t.setpos(x,y)
        t.down()
        # iterate over directions
        for move in directions:
            if move =='F':
               t.forward(length)
            elif move == 'L':
               t.lt(angle)
            elif move =='R':
               t.rt(angle)
            else:
               pass

s.exitonclick()
```

but I get an error message that I dont understand. See below

```
     >>> draw('FLFLFLFL',50,90)
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
        draw('FLFLFLFL',50,90)
      File "C:/Documents and Settings/RonnieE/Mina dokument/GradSchool/CSC401/Homework 
      7/test1.py", line 11, in draw
          t.up()
     TypeError: penup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
    s = Screen
    t = Turtle
```

should be:

```
    s = Screen()
    t = Turtle()
```

Otherwise, `s` and `t` are just new names for the `Screen` and `Turtle` classes.  Call the class to generate an *instance*.

Also, `s.exitonclick()` should be inside the `draw` definition (aligned with the `for`).